# How to get records with multiple where in many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I'm working on a Laravel version 9 project. At first, I explain the tables and relationships.
There are 3 tables:

`advertisements`, `advertisement_tags` and the pivot table `advertisement_advertisement_tag`.
As you can see `advertisements` and `advertisement_tags` has a many-to-many relationship.
Now I want to get the `advertisements` that only have specific ‍‍‍`advertisement_tags`. For example I send an array including [1,2,5]. I expect to get `advertisements` that have exactly `advertisement_tags` with 1,2 and 5 Id together, and I don't want to get `advertisements` that only have one of these tags 1,2 or 5. I mean I have tried `whereIn` clause.

If you can help me, there is no difference between pure `SQL` and `Query Builder`.
thanks

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking questions here. And do you want a SQL or Laravel solution?

Comment: @jarlh thank you for your advice, I will consider it. no difference between SQL or Laravel solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi sempley you can join the tables together then do your condition after that group your result by advertisement id then have condition to check each record have all tags count

I think this sample query below can help you to get concept

```
$tags=[1,2,5];
DB::table('advertisements')
->join('advertisement_tags','advertisements.id','advertisement_tags.ad_id')
->whereIn('advertisement_tags.tag_id',$tags)
->select('advertisements.*',DB:raw('count(advertisement_tags.*) as tag_count '))
->GoupBy('advertisements.id')
->Having('tag_count',count($tags))->get()
```

also you can check laravel [query Documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

How about using having in order to be sure that you got the correct number of tags for each advertisement?

```
SELECT advertisment_id
FROM advertisement_advertisement_tag
WHERE tag_id in($searched_tag_ids)
GROUP BY advertisment_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id)=$number_of_searched_tags
```

This query will return all advertisment_id's with all the tags ad then you can join this results with advertisements table to get all the info of the matching advertisement_id's.

Comment: your answer was correct too, thank you.